# Time limit fix and randomization

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make python run a short multiple choice quiz where each question is randomized each time the quiz is taken and there is a time limit for each question. I have a time limit, but it doesn't seem to work. At least, not until I give an answer. I'm also having trouble figure out how the questions would randomize properly. Below is the code that I'm working on. If possible, try to explain it as simple as possible. Thanks!

```
import time
import random


def run_quiz(questions):
    start_time = time.time()
    time_limit = 15
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
        if elapsed_time >= time_limit:
            break
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)) + f" questions right in a {time_limit}s time limit!")

class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer

def main():

   question_prompts = [
        "Quebec produces 3/4 of the world's supply of what?\n(a) Apples\n(b) Maple\n(c) Sugar\n\n",
        "Mochi is made from sweet, glutinous rice that came from which country?\n(a) South Korea\n(b) Mongolia\n(c) Japan\n\n",
        "Injeolmi is a Korean sticky rice cake coated in what?\n(a) Soybean powder\n(b) Sugar\n(c) Cocoa Powder\n\n",
        "What French pastry is defined by is caramelized outside and chewy, custard-like inside?\n(a) Canelé\n(b) Madeleine\n(c) Mille-feuille\n\n",
        "Baumkuchen is a cake that is poular in Japan, but came from which country?\n(a) Netherlands\n(b) Germany\n(c) Denmark\n\n",
        "What kind of cheese is used to make Tiramisu?\n(a) Marscapone\n(b) Brie\n(c) Mozzarella\n\n",
        "Zefirs are a Russian confection made from egg whites and sugar, and are similar to what?\n(a) Custard\n(b) Scrambled Eggs\n(c) Marshmallows\n\n",
        "Crepes are a thin French quickbread that are similar to what?\n(a) Pita\n(b) Pancakes\n(c) Tortillas\n\n",
        "S'mores came from which country?\n(a) Great Britain\n(b) Canada\n(c) United States\n\n",
        "Stroopwafels are a Dutch waffle-shaped cookies filled with what?\n(a) Caramel\n(b) Chocolate syrup\n(c) Condensed Milk\n\n"]

   questions = [
       Question(question_prompts[0], "b"),
       Question(question_prompts[1], "c"),
       Question(question_prompts[2], "a"),
       Question(question_prompts[3], "a"),
       Question(question_prompts[4], "b"),
       Question(question_prompts[5], "a"),
       Question(question_prompts[6], "c"),
       Question(question_prompts[7], "b"),
       Question(question_prompts[8], "c"),
       Question(question_prompts[9], "a")
    ]

   run_quiz(questions)

if __name__ == "__main__":  # Tell the Python interpreter to execute this main()
   main()
```

Comment: Do you want it to stop asking for input when the time limit is done?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to have it so that it displays the score when the time limit runs out and stops running.

Comment: Also, do you want each question to have 15 seconds? Or did you want all of the questions to have a cumulative of 15 seconds?

Comment: The former. I'm trying to have it so that you have a 15 second time limit on each individual question.

Comment: So, I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. Also, I'm trying to have the questions display in a random order when the quiz is retaken, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Tried what? (If you're talking about my answer, comment there instead)

Comment: I tried using the signal library, but it doesn't seem to be working. I keep getting an attribute error.

Comment: Can you paste the error? (and let's go to the comments on my answer)

Answer (score 0):

There is an in-built library called [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html)

Signal will allow you to interrupt your input if you do not press *enter* on time.

```py
import signal
import time
import random


def interrupted(signum, frame):
    "called when read times out"
    print ('You ran out of time! Press enter to go to your next question.')
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, interrupted)

def _input(prompt):
    try:
            print (prompt)
            foo = input()
            return foo
    except:
            # timeout
            return


def run_quiz(questions):
    start_time = time.time()
    time_limit = 15
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        # set alarm
        signal.alarm(time_limit)
        answer = _input(question.prompt)
        # disable the alarm after success
        signal.alarm(0)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("\nYou got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)) + f" questions right in a {time_limit}s time limit!")
    print(f"It took you {elapsed_time} to finish these questions.")

class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer

def main():

   question_prompts = [
        "Quebec produces 3/4 of the world's supply of what?\n(a) Apples\n(b) Maple\n(c) Sugar\n\n",
        "Mochi is made from sweet, glutinous rice that came from which country?\n(a) South Korea\n(b) Mongolia\n(c) Japan\n\n",
        "Injeolmi is a Korean sticky rice cake coated in what?\n(a) Soybean powder\n(b) Sugar\n(c) Cocoa Powder\n\n",
        "What French pastry is defined by is caramelized outside and chewy, custard-like inside?\n(a) Canelé\n(b) Madeleine\n(c) Mille-feuille\n\n",
        "Baumkuchen is a cake that is poular in Japan, but came from which country?\n(a) Netherlands\n(b) Germany\n(c) Denmark\n\n",
        "What kind of cheese is used to make Tiramisu?\n(a) Marscapone\n(b) Brie\n(c) Mozzarella\n\n",
        "Zefirs are a Russian confection made from egg whites and sugar, and are similar to what?\n(a) Custard\n(b) Scrambled Eggs\n(c) Marshmallows\n\n",
        "Crepes are a thin French quickbread that are similar to what?\n(a) Pita\n(b) Pancakes\n(c) Tortillas\n\n",
        "S'mores came from which country?\n(a) Great Britain\n(b) Canada\n(c) United States\n\n",
        "Stroopwafels are a Dutch waffle-shaped cookies filled with what?\n(a) Caramel\n(b) Chocolate syrup\n(c) Condensed Milk\n\n"]

   questions = [
       Question(question_prompts[0], "b"),
       Question(question_prompts[1], "c"),
       Question(question_prompts[2], "a"),
       Question(question_prompts[3], "a"),
       Question(question_prompts[4], "b"),
       Question(question_prompts[5], "a"),
       Question(question_prompts[6], "c"),
       Question(question_prompts[7], "b"),
       Question(question_prompts[8], "c"),
       Question(question_prompts[9], "a")
    ]

   new_questions = []
   for i in range(len(questions)):
      new_questions.append(questions.pop(random.randint(0,len(questions)-1)))

   run_quiz(new_questions)

if __name__ == "__main__":  # Tell the Python interpreter to execute this main()
   main()
```

**Edit:** For randomizing the order of the questions, you can create a new list and change the order like so:

```py
new_questions = []
for i in range(len(questions)):
   new_questions.append(questions.pop(random.randint(0,len(questions)-1)))

run_quiz(new_questions)
```

I have updated this code in the above, but I'm just showing you the specific are where this is working here.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mgrm2\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Final_Project.py", line 16, in <module>
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, interrupted)
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGALRM'

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: Wait, that wouldn't make a difference. SIGALRM should be found in every version.

Comment: I'm using version 3.9

Comment: That's what I'm using too... [it works here](https://replit.com/@12944qwerty/testing#main.py)

Comment: Also, when I tried looking into it, I didn't see SIGALRM pop up.

Comment: I'm not sure if this has to do with the interface I'm using or not. I'm using PyCharm

Comment: Oh, which OS are you using? signal.SIGALRM is only on Unix devices.

Comment: I'm using windows.

Comment: So then, is there an equivalent to sigalrm on Windows? I can't seem to find anything useful.

Comment: Possibly make a GUI? But that would be extreme for this type of project.

Comment: @Madeleine You can also make it so that you have infinite time, but you only get it right if you get it right in the time period.